How to publish a server-side Angular app on a server
I built a server-side Angular app using the following command:
ng build

Then, in dist directory, two folders and two files were created:

browser
server
3rdpartylicenses.txt
prerendered-routes.json

Where should I upload these folders and files on my server?
I use Plesk. And my Angular version is 18

You need to place the contents of the dist folder in the public web folder of your web server, for Plesk, the document root. Since the serving process for Angular SSR is Express, you should be able to run it the same way you'd run other Express programs: https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/
